# Is it possible to localize prefixes property(SI units) in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have graph and its x-axis labeled using SI units, I am trying to have the labels in Arabic (e.g k ---> الف), I was able to do this by string minubulation,

```
 var formatSi = d3.format(".2s");
 function formatAbbreviation(x) {
    var s = formatSi(x);
    case "k": s= s.slice(0, -1) + " الف";
    ....
    return s;
 }
```

Then I found that we can define our locale using `d3.formatDefaultLocale(definition)`[1](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#formatDefaultLocale) , but I am not sure what are the properties that we can use, it seems we can use the following:

```
var ru_RU = {
    "decimal": ",",
        "thousands": "\xa0",
        "grouping": [3],
        "currency": ["", " руб."],
        "dateTime": "%A, %e %B %Y г. %X",
        "date": "%d.%m.%Y",
        "time": "%H:%M:%S",
        "periods": ["AM", "PM"],
        "days": ["воскресенье", "понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота"],
        "shortDays": ["вс", "пн", "вт", "ср", "чт", "пт", "сб"],
        "months": ["Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"],
        "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
}
```

But none of these are related to the SI units, I found the SI units are used in global variable like this :

```
var map = Array.prototype.map,
    prefixes = ["y","z","a","f","p","n","µ","m","","k","M","G","T","P","E","Z","Y"];
```

In `[locale.js]`[2](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/main/src/locale.js)

My question, Can we localize these prefixes the same as we did with `decimal`, `currency`, ets...